# CsvHelper - mapping to non default constructor ignoring properties not included within constructor

Tags: c#, csvhelper

I have created the following basic example to show the issue i'm having. As you can see the User class has a constructor that takes 3 arguments (camelCase).

When parsing the rows region is never mapped. How do I get region to map, do I need to specify a specific configuration setting? It took me a log time to figure out the header names needed to match the constructor camel casing!

```
class Program
    {
        class User
        {
            public User(string firstName, string lastName, string email)
            {
                if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(firstName))
                {
                    throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(firstName));
                }

                if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(lastName))
                {
                    throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(lastName));
                }

                if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(email))
                {
                    throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(email));
                }

                FirstName = firstName;
                LastName = lastName;
                Email = email;
            }

            public string FirstName { get; private set; }

            public string LastName { get; private set; }

            public string Email { get; private set; }

            public string Region { get; set; }
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var s = new StringBuilder();
            s.AppendLine("email,firstName,lastName,Region");
            s.AppendLine("billy@bob.com,me,jerk,UK");
            s.AppendLine("you@u.com,me,fork,USA");

            using var reader = new StringReader(s.ToString());
            using var csv = new CsvReader(reader, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

            var records = csv.GetRecords<User>();

            foreach (var user in records)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Parsing row: {csv.Context.Row}");
                Console.WriteLine($"Email: {user.Email}");
                Console.WriteLine($"First Name: {user.FirstName}");
                Console.WriteLine($"Last Name: {user.LastName}");
                Console.WriteLine($"Region: {user.Region}");
            }
        }
    }
```

produces the following output

```
Parsing row: 2
Email: billy@bob.com
First Name: me
Last Name: jerk
Region:
Parsing row: 3
Email: you@u.com
First Name: me
Last Name: fork
Region:
```

I have also raised an issue on [GitHub](https://github.com/JoshClose/CsvHelper/issues/1482).

Comment: Maybe not your desired solution if it works, but would an optional "region = null" constructor parameter and property assignment work here?

Comment: Side note: You don't need the case to match if you provide a `PrepareHeaderForMatch`, like this: `csv.Configuration.PrepareHeaderForMatch = (header,index)=>header.ToLower();`

Comment: @Magnetron I have done extra work which involves PrepareHeaderForMatch, i just didn't include it here but thanks anyway

Comment: @GrahamMeehan not a bad suggestion, I've got several classes that will be mapped like this, I didn't want to have to change them just to get CSVHelper working, i'm currently doing a "manual" read until I can figure out this mapping issue

Comment: @Phil Well, I think you only have two options, either add a parameterless contructor or add another constructor that takes all properties. I don't think the library currently supports another way.

Comment: @Phill Actually there is a third option, which is [reading by hand](https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/examples/reading/reading-by-hand), which I believe is what you meant when you said that you're doing a "manual read".

Comment: @Magnetron yes that is what i meant by "manual" read.

Answer (score 0):

as @Magnetron pointed out in the comments, CsvHelper does not currently support this,

reply from author on [github issue](https://github.com/JoshClose/CsvHelper/issues/1482#issuecomment-604119402)

> Currently, you can only do constructor or member maps, but not both.
>   I'm thinking there shouldn't be an issue with having them both at the
>   same time though. This is something I'll have to look into.